# How add setText in input view AlertDialog

Tags: android, file, rename, android-alertdialog

I write an algorithm to rename a file, how can I print the current name in the input field?

```
 final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                                        .setTitle("Rename")
                                        .setMessage("Add new name:")
                                        .setView(input)
                                        .setPositiveButton("Ok", new OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                                String value = input.getText().toString();
                                                if (directory.isDirectory()) {
                                                    File from = new File(directory.getAbsolutePath());
                                                    File to = new File(directory.getParent() + "/" + value);
                                                    from.renameTo(to);
                                                } else {
                                                    File from = new File(directory.getAbsolutePath());
                                                    File to = new File(directory.getParent() + "/" + value + "." + checkFormat);
                                                    from.renameTo(to);
                                                }
                                                go(currentDirectory);
                                            }
                                        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                        // Do nothing.
                                    }
                                }).show();
```

I would greatly appreciate the help

Comment: Wouldn't the input field already contain the new name if the user renamed the file using the input field? Or am I not understanding your question?

Comment: I want to before he renamed it, he saw the old name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should work to put the old name in the input box.

```
File old = null;
if (directory.isDirectory()) {                                           
    old = new File(directory.getAbsolutePath());
}
final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
input.setText(old.toString());
...
//the rest of your code
```

Comment: Yeap! Thanks dear, maybe you know how else to do that this text has been selected? :)